# Azure Node.js Running Service Bus Queue Messages in Worker Role

Tags: node.js, azure

How do I setup the worker role to listen for server bus queue messages using the windows azure sdk ?

Currently I have this in my server.js worker role to listen for queue messages

```
var http = require('http')
    , config = require('./config')
    , azure = require('azure')
    , uuid = require('node-uuid');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    processServices(function () {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        res.end('hello world');
    });
}).listen(process.env.port);

function processServices(callback) {
    var sb1 = azure.createServiceBusService(config.serviceBusNamespace, config.serviceBusAccessKey);
    sb1.receiveQueueMessage('startup', function (error, m) {
        if (!error) {
            writeMessage(JSON.stringify(m), function () {
                callback();
            });
        }
        else {
            writeMessage(JSON.stringify(error), function () {
                callback();
            });
        }
    });
}

function writeMessage(message, callback) {
    var serviceClient = azure.ServiceClient;
    var ts1 = azure.createTableService(serviceClient.DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT, serviceClient.DEVSTORE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY, serviceClient.DEVSTORE_TABLE_HOST);

    ts1.getTable('Messages', function (error) {
        if (error === null) {
            var messageEntity = {
                PartitionKey: '0',
                RowKey: uuid(),
                Message: message
            };

            ts1.insertEntity('Messages', messageEntity, function (error, newMessage) {
                callback();
            });
        }
        else callback();
    });
}
```

And this in my server.js web role to setup the queue

```
var sb1 = azure.createServiceBusService(config.serviceBusNamespace, config.serviceBusAccessKey);
sb1.getQueue('startup', function (error, queue) {
    if (error) {
        sb1.createQueueIfNotExists('startup', function (error, queue) {
            if (!error)
                console.log("created startup queue 1: " + JSON.stringify(queue) + "\n");
            else
                console.log("don't got startup queue 1: " + JSON.stringify(error) + "\n");
        });
    }
    else console.log("created startup queue 2: " + JSON.stringify(queue) + "\n");
});
sb1.getQueue('serialnumbers', function (error, queue) {
    if (error) {
        sb1.createQueueIfNotExists('serialnumbers', function (error, queue) {
            if (!error)
                console.log("created serialnumbers queue 1: " + JSON.stringify(queue) + "\n");
            else
                console.log("don't got serialnumbers queue 1: " + JSON.stringify(error) + "\n");
        });
    }
    else console.log("created serialnumbers queue 2: " + JSON.stringify(queue) + "\n");
});
```

And this in my web role index.js file to send a message to the queue

```
var azure = require('azure')
    , config = require('../utils/config');

exports.index = function (req, res) {
    var sb1 = azure.createServiceBusService(config.serviceBusNamespace, config.serviceBusAccessKey);
    var startupMessage = {
        body: ''
    };

    sb1.getQueue('startup', function (error, queue) {
        if (!error) {
            sb1.sendQueueMessage('startup', startupMessage, function (error) {
                if (!error) {
                    console.log("sent startup message 1\n");

                    res.render('index', {
                        locals: {
                            pageTitle: 'Home'
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    console.log("didn't send startup message 1: " + JSON.stringify(error) + "\n");

                    res.render('index', {
                        locals: {
                            pageTitle: 'Home'
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            res.render('index', {
                locals: {
                    pageTitle: 'Home'
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

How do I get it so that the worker role listens and executes when the web role runs the index.js file?

Currently its not doing that, the messages are sitting in the queue but aren't being read by the worker role?

How do I get the worker role to read the message from the queue?

Should I run a cron job or use socket.io?  I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with npm **azure** package that it works via HTTP underneath, and as you know HTTP is request/response protocol. (Unfortunately in this application layer there is no things like SignalR or similar other "push" type communication). So the only way is to pull for messages -((.

But there is another way to consume (listen) for messages, if you use AMQP protocol.

There is npm package called [amqp10](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp10) (promise-based, AMQP 1.0 compliant node.js client), there you subscribe to messages and start listen, concept similar to httpServer, or expressjs. On their npmjs package home page you find docs and samples.

In short it looks something like this:
..

```
async function sample( {connectionString, topicSubscriptionPath} ){
   const { Client, Policy } = require('amqp10');
   const client = new Client(Policy.Utils.RenewOnSettle(1, 1, Policy.ServiceBusTopic));
   const connection = await client.connect(connectionString);
   const receiver = await connection.createReceiver(topicSubscriptionPath);

   receiver.on('message', (message) => {
         try {
           // here is your brokered message, do whatever u need to do
           receiver.accept(message); //if can be marked as processed, aka can be deleted from service bus
         } catch (error) {
           this.receiver.reject(message); //return back to service bus
         }
       });
   }
sample(buildConnectionString(), 'subscriptionNameInYourTopic');

function buildConnectionString(){
  //very specific format, keys you can find in your azure subscription
   return `amqps://${sharedAccessKeyName}:${sharedAccessKey}@${queueEndpoint}`;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need continuously poll queue with .receiveQueueMessage method, until you receive the message from the queue. Time intervals between polls are completelly up to you.

Comment: hi bbbonthemoon, according to the code i've written can you give me an example of what you mean ? cheers

Comment: well, the thing is, that Service Bus queue client, doesnt wait for the message to be received, when you poll with receiveQueueMessage(), it just checks if there is message for you, if yes it receives it, of not - it receives nothing and leaves. So you need to call this method again and again until message is received. Making endless cycle in async environment is separate topic, I usually do that with events. I check the queue on custom event, and trigger the event when I'm ready to poll again.

Comment: ok bbbonthemoon thanks, i thought as much, the best thing suited for that with node.js is the cron module so i'll use that. cheers

Comment: I don't think this is accurate. The call to receiveQueueMessage() will check and *wait* until after the timeout interval passes, which can be set [up to 24 days](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh767287.aspx). Much less expensive to long poll as you are being charged for each poll. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802604.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that Joel! Was pooling every 5 seconds and it was working awfully, not picking up messages until ages after. Now it works a treat!